# Allowing users to select options from a dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My app allows users to create profiles and enter information (description, name, etc..). I'd like for them to be able to select their language from a dropdown and have that choice saved to their record in the User table.

I understand that I have to have a separate `languages` table, a `language_id` field on the Profile table and using `options_from_collection_for_select` to create the actual dropdown.

My question is what do I need to do to the model/controller files to make this all work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a model named `Language`, this table will be responsible for storing all the languages. What I think: It would have one field named `language` of type string.

```
rails g model Language language:string # though you don't need ':string' part
```

In app/models/language.rb:

```
class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

Now, you need to add the `language_id` to the users table, and you would run the following migration:

```
rails g migration add_language_id_to_users language:references
```

And update the `User` model accordingly:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :language
  # other code
end
```

And then, from your `form`, you need to send a `language_id` when you pass other parameters to create a user, and in the controller, you will have to permit `language_id` like following:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :language_id)
end
```

And in your controller code, you just need to create a user as usual, and Rails will do the magic for you.

In controller, *usual code*:

```
@user = User.new(user_params)
```

Comment: You are welcome. If you think the answer is valid, and helped you, you can accept it.